# Nonempty finite set is not open but is bounded - metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I'm trying to show that if we have a non-empty finite subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ it is not an open set but it is bounded.

I have managed to show it is closed. Also, I'm aware that singleton sets are closed.

Open:
Let $ A = \{x_{1}, x_{2}, \dots, x_{k}\}$ be a non-empty finite subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}.$ To show it is not an open set, I am trying to show that if we draw a Ball around a point in $A$ it won't be an interior point.

Let $ r > 0$ and consider $B_{r}(x_{1}) = \{y \in A : d(y, x_{1}) < r\}.$ But I'm not too sure how to proceed. I've read that this shouldn't be able to contain any open balls, but I can't see why?

Bounded: Since this is a finite set, it will have a supremum and an infimum. Would the boundedness be as simple as the fact that every point in the finite set will be between these?

Thanks.

Comment: " I am trying to show that if we draw a Ball around a point in A it won't be an interior point."  Strategy 1: Prove every open ball in $\mathbb R^2$ is an infinite set but every subset of a finite set must be finite.  Strategy  2(probably the intended strategy); Find a adius of an open ball around $x_i$ that small enough so that $x_i$ is the only point of $A$ so all the other points of $B_r(x_i)$ won't be in $A$.

Comment: @fleablood yes my intended approach is the second one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove a point, $w$, is not interior of a set $A$ the strategy is usually always be the same.

You prove that for any possible $r>0$, no matter how small, there will always be a point in $\mathbb R^2$ not in the set $A$ that is closer to $w$ than $r$.

Two things come to mind:  For any $r>0$ then $B_r(w) = \{y\in \mathbb R^2| d(w,y) < r\}$ will have an infinite number of points; all closer to $w$ than $r$.  ($\mathbb R^2$ is the entire space and for any point distance you will always be able to find points within that distance.  So there are infinitely many points in $B_r(w).)

But $A$ has only *finitely* many points.  So if $B_r(w)$, do matter how small, has infinite points it must have points that are not in $A$ and these points are closer to $w$ then $r$. And that will always be true no matter how small $r$ is.

So $w$ can not be an interior point and $A$ is not open.

......

The only trouble with this proof, it the picky teacher will ask you:  How do you know that for every $r$ no matter how small that $B_r(w) =\{$ all the point in $\mathbb R^2$ within a distance of $r$ of $w\}$ is infinite.   And how do you know that if it is infinite it must have points not contained in a finite set.

.......

A more practical strategy.  Is that if you that an $r>0$ and take $B_r(w)=\{$all to points closer to $w$ than the distance $r\}$ then if take an even *smaller* $s: r>s>0$ then all tha points of $B_s(w) =\{$ all the points within $s$ of $w\}$ will be withing $r$ of $w$ (because $s$ is an even smaller distance).

So to say a point $w$ is *not* an interior point of $A$ is to say in effect:  We can always find a point not in $A$ that is close to $w$ no matter how close we look.

Now $A$ is finite:  So pick a point $w$.  Consider all the points $x_i\in A$ where $x_i \ne w$ and consider the distance $d_i :=d(w,x_i)$.  There are finite number of these distances, they are all positive, and as it is a finite set there must be a minimum distance.  So take the the smallest such distance and call it $s$.

All the points in $\mathbb R^2$ that are closer to $w$ than $s$ and are not equal to $w$ are *not* in $A$ because the are closer to $w$ than $w$ is to any other element in $A$.  So they are not in $A$.

So THAT means $w$ can't be an interior point because you can always find a point close to $w$ that isn't in $A$.

======

> Bounded: Since this is a finite set, it will have a supremum and an infimum. Would the boundedness be as simple as the fact that every point in the finite set will be between these?

ALmost but no.

$A \subset \mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R^2 \ne \mathbb R$.  There is no order on $\mathbb R^2$ so $A$ dos not have infimum or supremum.

However if you take the set $D = \{d(x,y)| x,y \in A\}$ then *that* set is $D\subset \mathbb R$.  and *it* is finite so *it* has a supremum. (It actually has a *maximum*).  So let $d = \sup D$ and then for any two points $w,v\in A$ then $d(w,y)\in D$ so $d(w,y) < d$.

And therefore $A$ is bounded.

Answer (score 4):

Since $A$ is finite, the number
$$S = \min\{d(x_i,x_j) \mid i \ne j, x_i, x_j \in A\}
$$
is positive. For any $0 < s \le S$, letting $B(x_i,s)$ be the open ball around $x_i$ of radius $s$, it follows that $A \cap B(x_i,s) = \{x_i\}$. But surely $B(x_i,s)$ contains a point other than $x_i$ (can you explicitly describe such a point?), and therefore $B(x_i,s) \not\subset A$.

Here's the contradiction: If there exists $r > 0$ such that $B(x_i,r) \subset A$ then, letting $s = \min\{S,r\}$, it would follow that $0 < s \le S$ and that $B(x_i,s) \subset A$.

Answer (score 2):

An open ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$ has uncountably many points, so any non-empty finite (or even countable) subset cannot contain an open ball around any of its points, and thus cannot be open.

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, there is no good notion of 'supremum' and 'infimum' in the same way there is in $\mathbb{R}^1$. So this argument doesn't work.

However, if you take the set of distances $\{d(x_1, 0), d(x_2, 0), \dots , d(x_k, 0) \}$, this does have a maximum, call it $r$.
Then $A \subset B_{r+1}(0)$, and so $A$ is bounded.

Comment: thanks. I still don't understand the open ball in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. The boundedness makes sense!

Comment: You can maybe think about it in terms of a proof by contradiction.
Let's assume to the contrary that $A$ is open. Then by definition of an open set, there must be some open ball $B \subseteq A$. But then $|B| \leq |A|$ (|| means cardinality). Since the ball $B$ is not finite, $A$ cannot be finite, which is a contradiction. 

Reading over the initial post, I suspect your confusion may come from what it means for a set to be open. A set $A$ is open if, for every point $x$ inside the set, there exists some radius $r$ such that $B_r(x) \subseteq A$.

Comment: is $|B|$ nor finite because we can choose any radius that we want for the ball? I understand everything else. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't matter what radius you choose. For any $r>0$ and any $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$, the ball $B_r(x)$ contains uncountably many points (if you aren't convinced, show that you can find an injection from some open interval $(0,1)$ into the ball).

Comment: I will try and do this injection as an exercise.